# Firebase Connection Killed

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have integrated Firebase into my iOS project. I have been using Firebase for years across many projects. This specifically is using the Firestore. I can authenticate fine and write to the database. However, after the write is complete, even though it's successful, I receive the following message:

> Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server.  Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly

The bundleID was copied and pasted directly from the app to the Firebase setup. I even deleted the app from Firebase and created it again. I have downloaded the `GoogleService-Info.plist` and I checked that the bundle there matches the bundle of the app. I can see nothing wrong here and again functionality is working fine.

The only instance I saw of this message browsing around was with a non-US based developer and it was suggested that additional config was required. However, that is not the situation for me. What else might cause this error to be generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message seems to point towards Realtime Database, despite your interest in Cloud Firestore.

I recommend:

1. Making sure you're using the latest SDK. Old SDK versions (before mid 2020) might *require* the Realtime Database URL to be present in the `plist` file, which isn't always the case anymore.
2. If step 1 doesn't solve the problem, you can:

   1. Force the creation of a Realtime Database instance in the Firebase console.
   2. Download the updated `plist` file and add it to your project.

If you end up with the second solution, can you comment with the SDK version you're using, so that I can check for issues in that?

Comment: I started following your suggestion #2 and it worked after step #1. That is, I created the realtime database from the console and immediately after, without downloading anything else, the error went away. I am using Firebase 7.9.1 via SPM. I have been using SPM for Firebase Firestore across numerous other projects without this issue. Very odd, but thanks so much for the suggestion above which got to the answer if not yet the reason.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, and the clear steps you took. 